# when trying to create calendar control in asp.net using ajax it throws an error

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I am trying to create a calendar control in asp.net using ajax it throws me an error

> Unknown server tag 'cci:CalendarExtender'

The code is:

```
<%@ Register Assembly ="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cci"  %>
<asp:TextBox ID="date1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="img1" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.png"/>
<cci:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="cal1" PopupbuttonID="img1" TargetControlID="date1" Format="dd/mm/yyyy"></cci:CalendarExtender>
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not using script Manager on your Page.

Don't forget to add the script manager - though I don't think that would account for the error

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```